# adding blur effect to background of a log in view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am setting a background image to a parse login view controller. But also want to add this background How can I achieve this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "Melbourne")
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

The problem is that this blurs everything including all the buttons and username and password fields. What can I do?

Comment: send blurEffectView to back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are adding your blur view over all the subviews of the view controllers.

try to insert at specific index in view hierarchy.

I have no proper idea of the view hierarchy of your viewController.
Do it using try&Error method like below.

try below code.

```
view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, atIndex: 1);
```

if not works try by increasing the index value 2 and so on.

```
view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, atIndex: 2);// if not change it to 3
```

It will surely works with specific value.